# Delete checkbox and button from the LinearLayout

Tags: android

I am creating a checkbox list with a button programmatically. For updating purpose I need to delete the old checkbox list and button before creating the new one in the `delete_element` method. How can I delete the checkbox and the button from the LinearLayout?

I appreciate any help.

```
    private void createCheckboxList(final ArrayList<Integer> items) {
        final ArrayList<Integer> selected = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lila);
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
            cb.setText(String.valueOf(items.get(i)));
            cb.setId(items.get(i));
            ll.addView(cb);

        }
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 150));
        btn.setText("submit");
        ll.addView(btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {}

}
```

Comment: set their visibility gone

Comment: @Logic: how can I find the id of the checkboxes and the button hte the ` remove_element` method?

Comment: make them private so that you can access in the whole class

Comment: What should I make private to access in hte wohle class? please can you add some code to know how can I set their visibility to GONE? also how can I find their id to set it to gone?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need do is to rethink your design, you need to go by Adapter approach. A listView is created with your child elements populated by an adapter which holds the values of child elements. The selected or particular position child item can added or deleted or modified or saved.

Have a look at this link for Adapter Listview example:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html